# scroll bar doesn't scroll to the last view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with my scroll view

I have tow toolbar one on the top and one on the bottom, and these tool bars should be always on the top of other views

when I scroll down the last view its behind the bottom bar and not shown

this is a pic to show you what I mean :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4lj_Q-eciA7N19meUJuOThWanM/view?usp=sharing

in the red circle there is a view behind that bar I want the view to be shown in the same time the bottom bar still on the top of other views

this is my layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.wujhaat.wujhaatod.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/end_bar"
    layout="@layout/end_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/subRoot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.wujhaat.wujhaatod.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basic_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nametv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/basic_info"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nametv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailtv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailtv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobiletv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/email"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/mobile"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mobiletv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:hint="0512345678"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adultnotv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/adult_no"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/adult_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adultnotv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:entries="@array/traveler_no_spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/childnotv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adult_spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/child_no"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/child_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/childnotv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:entries="@array/traveler_no_spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infanttv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/child_spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/infant_no"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/infant_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/infanttv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:entries="@array/traveler_no_spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/visatv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/infant_spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/visa"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/visa_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visatv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:entries="@array/yes_no" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/visatv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visa_spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/visa"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/visa_spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visatv1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:entries="@array/yes_no" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/visatv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visa_spinner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:text="@string/visa"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/visa_spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/visatv2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:entries="@array/yes_no" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please I need your help???

Comment: please post the image here, do we need to send a view request for you on google drive?

Comment: I can't because I don't have 10 repetition points I edit the link so any one can see it.

Comment: where is the red circle , post your expected view. you can draw it in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `ScrollView` xml

```
android:layout_above="@id/end_bar"
```

This will set your `ScrollView` to appear relative to your toolbars, fitting it in the space between them, instead of placing them over top of your `ScrollView`

You may also need to add `android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"` if it's appearing underneath your top toolbar.